# Quartiles and other parameters in groupby on multiple keys in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, quartile

**df columns are as below:**

```
  Key1   Key2   Val1
```

**Output needed**
I want groupby output where Val1 column has values clubbed together with **groupby in python on keys Key1 and Key2**.

**Output expected: df2  [groupby on key1 and key2]**

```
Key1 Key2 Val1  Count Sum Q1  Q2  Q3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a **function to calculate Q1, Q2 and Q3: 25th, 50th and 75th percentiles** as below:

```
def percentile(n):
    def percentile_(x):
        return np.percentile(x, n)
    percentile_.__name__ = 'percentile_%s' % n
    return percentile_
```

Now you can use **named aggregation** as mentioned below to obtain count, sum and the 3 quartile columns as you want.

```
      df2 = (df.groupby(["Key1", "Key2"])
             .agg(Count=(" Val1", 'count'),    
                  Sum=('Val1','sum'),        
                  Q1= (' Val1',percentile(25), #This is for first quartile
                  Q2= (' Val1',percentile(50), #2nd Quartile
                  Q3= (' Val1',percentile(75)) #This is for Quartile 3
```

Random eg.

**df** say was

```
Key1   Key2  Val1
a       a     1
a       a     2
a       a     3
a       a     4
b       b     5
b       b     6
b       b     7
b       b     8
```

**df2** will have below columns as asked for groupby on keys Key1 and Key2.

```
Key1 Key2  Count  Sum   Q1  Q2  Q3
 a    a     4     10    1   2.5 3
 b    b     4     6.5   5   6.5 7
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Key1','Key2'])['Val1']
         .agg([('Count','count'), 
               ('Sum','sum'), 
               ('Q1', lambda x: x.quantile(0.25)),
               ('Q2', lambda x: x.quantile(0.5)),
               ('Q3', lambda x: x.quantile(0.75))])
```

Comment: Probably you should explain your answer a little bit